# Calling JS within a simple form input (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple form in my application, i have an inline js to set field name and
unset when user clicks on the field and modify it as shown below

`input type="text" class="ftext" value="First Name" onclick="if(this.value=='First Name') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='First Name'"`

I am trying to do this with simple form inpt `<%= f.input :password, :required => true, :class => "ftext" %>`, but cannot able to find any solution in web.

Please suggest me on this.

thanks,
Balan

Comment: It will be better if you not using inline javascript and made javascript function for that.

Comment: Ok. so i need to write function for each and every input i use?
Thought using inline js would simplify it.
Even so is it possible to use js in simple form input?

Comment: You are going to check the condition on click so it becomes easy to write javascript related to field input in one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by using **"input_html"** option as shown below :

```
<%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { :onclick => "customFunction()", :class => "stext", :style => "padding-left:93px;width:170px;" } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything like this works for rails 5

```
<%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true, onclick: "yourFunction()" %>
```